# Join m binary trees to get a single binary tree with minimum possible height

Tags: binary-tree

In a collection of binary trees, T1, . . . , Tk. Now I need to join all trees to form a single binary tree that has the minimum height. To join two trees Ti and Tj , the root of one tree must be made a child of some node of the other tree that has less than two children.

If we join the trees one by one to get one single binary tree, what is the deciding factor at each step while joining 2 trees ? Total no of joins will be k-1; but which 2 trees to join at the ith step ?

My approach: Take the 2 trees with minimum heights and join them. Continue this until you get a single tree. But this approach seems to be wrong.

Comment: To join all binary trees you need a tree, you create a root and bind all childs in 2 degree

Comment: @matmahnke what is bind all children in 2 degree ?

Comment: now I understand your question, and i guess that your approach seems the most correct. sorry about my english

Comment: Going by the examples in https://www.isical.ac.in/~dfslab/2019/exams/lab-test2.pdf, it seems like a strategy of choosing the tallest tree with the highest open leaf might be a place to start. Example 2 on page 5 starts with the G tree, which has a height of 3 and an open leaf at level 2, to which it attaches the A tree, which has a height of 2 and an open leaf at level 2.